# Android web shop app with listview

Tags: android, web

I'm wondering how to create app like **e-bay** or something with listview with items loaded from internet.

Do I need to create `php script` that returns an xml, and then parse and show in a list.

Or make with Json? Or are there any other ways?

What is the popular and best way?

Comment: either of those will work. And which is "best" cannot be could not be determined by us given how little we know about your data.

Comment: How do you measure "best way"?

Comment: How did it facebook app? I', sure that it wasn't a webview. What method they used? And what method used Ebay? Thanks anyway!